# List out of range while comparing

Tags: python, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to see if sum of two objects in a list is equal to a number or not. I wrote this code and it gave me an error - list out of range, when I try printing the index of the objects. I don't see the error, when I print the objects -

```
ls = [2,8,12,7]
for x in ls:
    for y in ls[1::]:
        if x + y == 9:
            print(ls[x],ls[y]) # gives error
            print(x,y) # works fine
```

I was able to resolve it by using enumerate function but would like to know why I'm getting an error for the above code.

Working code -

```
ls = [2,8,12,7]
for inx,x in enumerate(ls):
    for iny,y in enumerate(ls[1::]):
        if x + y == 9:
            print(inx,iny)
```

Comment: for y in ls[1::]: return element of list ls, start from index 1 [8,12,17] . Then you do this: ls[y] where y is 8, your list only have 4 elements (index from 0 to 3) and you call its 8th index. Thats why it returns index out of range.

Comment: What the other answers say; you're basically making an error when you try to access ls[x] or ls[y] and the x and y values are too large because they are the values of the items in your list and not the index values, so you get an index out of range error.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a list with a for loop, e.g. `for x in ls`, you're iterating over the *values* of the list, not the indexes. Therefore, x will be 2, 8, 12, 7, in that order. And since your list only has 4 elements, there is no element at index 8, which is causing the index out of range exception when trying to access `ls[x]`.